# Плагин facebook-коментарии

Tags: javascript, плагин, facebook-api

Доброго всем!

Вот это в инете работает: [пример плагина комментов от морда-книга](http://jsfiddle.net/g7yae/13/). А когда тестирую на локалке - нет. WTF так происходит?

```
<!-- FaceBook - comments plugin -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.kansk.land.ru" data-num-posts="5" data-width="470"></div>

<!-- End plugin from FaceBook -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1
```

Скорее всего, из за этого.
Видать, с сервера в инете это срабатывает по другому, нежели из браузере локально.